# How to correctly code this function such that it calculates the sum of each digit of the int?

Tags: c++

I have written a function that converts a 5-digit zip code into bar code. However, I also need to calculate the sum of each digit in order to proceed to the last step. I have attempted to do so but Visual Studio says that the variable sum is uninitiallized. I can tell I am doing something wrong but I don't know why. Can someone explain why and give some suggestion to correct my code? Thank you for your response.

```
void bar_code(int zip)
{
    int sum;

    for (int number = 0; number <= 4; number ++)
    {

        int d = zip / pow( 10 , 4 - number);
        if (d == 0) { cout << "||:::"; };
        if (d == 1) { cout << ":::||"; };
        if (d == 2) { cout << "::|:|"; };
        if (d == 3) { cout << "::||:"; };
        if (d == 4) { cout << ":|::|"; };
        if (d == 5) { cout << ":|:|:"; };
        if (d == 6) { cout << ":||::"; };
        if (d == 7) { cout << "|:::|"; };
        if (d == 8) { cout << "|::|:"; };
        if (d == 9) { cout << "|:|::"; };

        sum += d;

        int update = pow(10, 4 - number);

        zip = zip % update;



    }

    if (sum == 0) { cout << "||:::"; };
    if (sum == 1) { cout << ":::||"; };
    if (sum == 2) { cout << "::|:|"; };
    if (sum == 3) { cout << "::||:"; };
    if (sum == 4) { cout << ":|::|"; };
    if (sum == 5) { cout << ":|:|:"; };
    if (sum == 6) { cout << ":||::"; };
    if (sum == 7) { cout << "|:::|"; };
    if (sum == 8) { cout << "|::|:"; };
    if (sum == 9) { cout << "|:|::"; };
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is uninitialized: `int sum;` and then later `sum += d;`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, sum is not initialize properly since you do `sum += d;`. Do `int sum = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `sum`. Value initialize it using `int sum{}` or `int sum = x` before trying to add `d` to it.